# What is the correct way to clean all the shared pointers that are in a map?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management, shared-ptr, visual-studio-2010

I have an object that has a map of shared pointers.

```
class A
{
   map<string, shared_ptr<B>> child;
}
```

Would the destructor for A take care of destroying the pointers in the map? Do need to manually reset the map's values?

I am seeing a _`Resetp<> and _Ref_coun`t hold on to 2 objects and I was curious if the problem was that I was not cleaning the nodes.

Comment: In addition to sharth's excellent answer: IIRC (please correct me if I'm wrong, someone) the STL containers make a copy when you append something to them. So if your original `shared_ptr` is not out of range at the point you request the ref count (for example, you have written `shared_ptr<Node> ptr(node); child["myPtr"] = ptr;` on consecutive lines and then immediately request the refcount) you would see two refcounts, as you have two `shared_ptr` objects (`ptr` and its copy `child["myPtr"]`) referencing `node`.

Comment: @CompuChip: Not any more. They will move objects into the container in most situation only copying if there is no other option.

Comment: @LokiAstari: The object can only be moved if you provide an _rvalue_. CompuChip's example provides an _lvalue_, which must be copied, so you would indeed see a refcount of 2.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are using `boost::shared_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`, or something else that is similar, then when `A` is destroyed, the shared_ptrs will all have their reference counts decremented by one, which may cause their own destruction.